# View HTTP GET Request cookies

Tags: c#, cookies

Here is my code, simple request, response HTTP;

```
    string uri = "https://forum.donanimhaber.com/forumid_12/tt.htm";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string oku = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

if you go to this address and watch the network traffic at first get which is "tt.htm",at cookie section there is forum net id session cookie. i want to get this cookie's value in my program and i'm looking at web for this thing but none of them did work. thank you.

Comment: response.Cookies?

Comment: yes but that shows me something else. not the cookie i want

Comment: What is the exact name of the cookie you are looking for? Is it coming from the same domain or third party site?

Comment: ASP.NET_SessionId ??

Comment: yes halit i gotta get that cookie's value.

exact name is "Forum.NET_SessionId"

Comment: donanimhaber sends  seperate request to generate session. 
(like this)
https://forum.donanimhaber.com/service/v1/session/set?version=-1&securekey=466386AE3F5F56EB1D9BE4DD46B78DC6&projectType=Forum&forumId=12

Comment: So what does it mean? should i request that url to get the cookie i want?

Comment: @ZekiKral Yes. You must send request to that url to generate sessionId

Comment: i sent request to this address(which one you gave to me);https://forum.donanimhaber.com/service/v1/session/set?version=-1&securekey=466386AE3F5F56EB1D9BE4DD46B78DC6&projectType=Forum&forumId=12
and i added this code below of response;
Console.WriteLine(response.Cookies.ToString());
it outputs "System.Net.CookieCollection"

Comment: because its a collection. try to loop it

Comment: foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}, String: {1}", cook.Domain, cook.ToString());
                }

Comment: well i am kinda newbie. would you help me a little bit. i could learn how to loop but you are here and i don't want to lose you

Comment: ya siteyi mahvettin. biraz video eğitimleri falan izleyeydin . sil bu soruyu buradan işin bitince.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/r2agmz.png

here what is outputs. as you can see its not what i need :(

Comment: tamam silerimde bir çözelim sabahtan beri uğraşıyorum deniyorum her şeyi olmuyor

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
        string uri = "https://forum.donanimhaber.com/service/v1/session/set?version=-1&securekey=123213&projectType=Forum&forumId=12";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string oku = readStream.ReadToEnd();


        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}, Name: {1}, value: {2}", cook.Domain, cook.Name,cook.Value); 

        }
```

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/WQyVY2.png

isn't giving me the cookie's value i need. what is your output?

Comment: adamlar güvenlik önlemi almış olabilirler. securekey parametresinden  birşeyleri kontrol ediyordur. Ip karşılaştırması gibi.

Comment: ya yok almamışlardır. normal network trafficte gözüküyor işte ordan direk çekemiyor muyuz böyle alengirli işlere giriyoruz? hı?

Comment: benim kodu kopyala yapıştır çalışmıyorsa modemini bir kapat aç senin ip'yi engellemiş olabilirler.

Comment: yaptım aynı hala düzelmiyor. Sende farklı mı çıkarıyor ekrana?

Comment: neyse bloklandım herhalde başka platformlardan da denerim. sende çalışıyorsa illaki çalışır son bir şey daha sen bu url'yi nerden çıkardın peki?

Comment: waooov get sonrasında veriyor onu. her gün yeni şeyler öğreniyoruz. siliyim mi soruyu?

Comment: silemiyorum başkaları cevap vererek emek harcadı diyor. özür dilerim votelar için